# Spring Conversion in form backing bean

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf, java-time

I have actually two questions. Both are occuring in the same situation, which is as follows:

I am working with spring and thymeleaf and I want to post a form to the server, which works fine but the server is not able to convert some of the submited data to the types of the attributes of my bean.

The form:

```
<form th:action="@{/demo}}" th:object="${myBean}" method="post">
    <label>date</label>
    <input type="date" th:field="*{date}">
    <label>type</label>
    <select th:filed="*{type}">
        <option th:each="type: ${types}" th:value="${type.id}" th:text="${type.name}"></option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The beandefinition:

```
@lombok.Data
public class MyBean{
    private ZonedDateTime date;
    private MyType type;
}
```

Problems:

1. The value of the date-input can not be converted to java.time.ZonedDateTime
2. The value of the select (which will be posted as a number) can not be converted to an object of type MyType. Which I would have expexted because MyType is a JPA Entity and has a `org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository` defined for it.

I would be delighted if any of you could help me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it on my own.

The Value of the Date-Input is sent as String i.e. "2017-12-31" to be able to use a ZonedDateTime in my form backing bean i had to register a custom converter. Here is the Code:

```
public class ZonedDateTimeConverter implements Converter<String, ZonedDateTime> {
@Override
public ZonedDateTime convert(String source) {
    return ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDate.parse(source, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")), LocalTime.of(00, 00),
            ZoneId.systemDefault());
}
```

}

and in the `WebMvcConfigurer` i registered it with:

```
@Override
public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
    registry.addConverter(new ZonedDateTimeConverter());
}
```

For the second problem the solution was even more simple, the only thing i hand to do is to annotate my Application with `@EnableSpringDataWebSupport` which in turn registered some converters for my Entity-Beans